# Error undefined reference to symbol 'FCGX_InitRequest' on compiler c++ FreeBSD

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, fastcgi, freebsd

I'm trying to compile a C++ code, but a error happen:

> undefined reference to symbol 'FCGX_InitRequest'

I'm using freebsd, and I already installed the lfcgi library.

The code what i using to do this:

> g++49 echo-cpp.cpp -lfcgi++ -o hello_world

And my code:

```
#include "fcgio.h"

int main() {
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();

    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    while ( FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0 ) {
        fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);

        std::cout.rdbuf(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);

        std::cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                     "\r\n"
                     "<h1>Hello world :)</h1>";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thanks!

---- EDIT ----

I changed the command to compile

> g++49 echo-cpp.cpp -lfcgi++ -lfcgi -o hello_world

And the error has changed:

```
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long)'                                                 
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()'                                                            
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()'                                           
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios()'                                                                    
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf()'                                                        
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()'                                                            
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)'                                            
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()'                                                            
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::ios_base::init(void*)'                                                                                                          
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc()'                                                               
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()'                                           
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekpos(std::__1::fpos<__mbstate_t>, unsigned int)'                        
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf()'                                                         
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir, unsigned int)'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long)'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::pbackfail(int)'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, long)'
//usr/local/lib/libfcgi++.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `FCGX_InitRequest` is a C language function defined in the C library `libfcgi`, not
in the C++ library `libfcgi++`. You need to link both, and the C++ library depends on the C library. So
replace `-lfcgi++` with `-lfcgi++ -lfcgi` in your linkage.